# Can I load a datatable after a modal pops up with a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have a page that loads another form through a modal and I want to get datatables to work with it.

For example, here's the code on my page:

```
#app/views/product/index.html.erb
...
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag "Issues", nil, class: "col-sm-3 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <%= link_to "[view]", issues_path(@product), remote: true, class: "control-label" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<%= render 'layouts/largeModal' %>
```

```
#app/views/issues/index.js.erb
$('.modal-title').html('<center>Issues</center>');
$('.body').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "form") %>');
$('#largeModal').modal('toggle');
```

```
#app/views/issues/_form.html.erb
<div class="modal-body">

<table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-responsive" id="issues">
...
</table>
...
</div>
```

So the form loads up just fine in a modal, but I need to get datatables to work with it since it has numerous results. Do I have to call datatables after replacing the HTML of the modal where it says

```
$('.body').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "form") %>');
```

Or how else would I load the datatables considering the form isn't really displayed until the modal is called? I have my modals set up this way for a particular reason, so I'd prefer to not have to call my modal a different way to get this working.

Comment: Can you create a js file specifically for the modal, and put the datatables initialisation code is within the `$(document).ready` section? I have done this in MVC, not sure if its applicable to your situation.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand, my apologies. So instead of rendering a partial that's an html.erb file, convert to a js and surround the modal with $(document).ready?

Comment: no, the datatables init code is in $(document).ready, so it doesn't fire until the modal is loaded

Comment: That worked flawlessly! Thanks so much!!